# Use iOS Siri programmatically to read iPhone SMS

Tags: ios, iphone, siri

I need to know whether apple has provided any way yet, to read the new incoming iPhone Sms in our iOS app programmatically? If not, is there a way that we can use siri programatically in the app to read the new incoming sms to the user?

Comment: Siri is not opened to developers yet. So it wouldn't be possible to programmatically enable Siri to dictate the SMS for you. Also you don't have access to the user's SMS. So you won't able to read the SMS programmatically.

Comment: Is there no other way to develop an iPhone app that can read aloud an sms to the user?

Comment: AFAIK I don't think you can do that

Comment: AFAIK Amazon Watch app have one STT (probably siri) service.